# Is it possible to view a branch of a website's clone using git?

Tags: git, web, git-branch

I have a working version of a website that is a clone of the DocumentRoot located in my /home/dmaxwell/public_html folder.  I would like to branch off of my working clone and try some different things, however, when I go to check to see any progress the master branch is the version that the browser shows.  Is there a way to get the browser to show the experimental branch or am I limited to only using the master branch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your website will show whatever is present in the code checked out. If you want to view the branch, check it out:

```
 git checkout branch_name
```

Comment: I thought I had tried this before and it didn't work, but it's showing the different branches now, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

you can switch back and fourth between branches using

```
git checkout <branch>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can "clone" your branch to a different location under the same web-server or under different web-server and see it there. This is not really git related more like what your deployment/infrastructure is.